# Cannot write file '..../public/scripts/script.js' because it would overwrite input file

Tags: typescript

I have a project created in Visual Studio 2017 using the  TypeScript `Basic Node.js Express 4 Application` template.

I have a file `/public/scripts/script.js` meant for download to the client. When I tried to build the application I get:

> TS5055 Cannot write file 'd:/documents/visual studio 2017/Projects/ExpressApp/ExpressApp/public/scripts/script.js' because it would overwrite input file.

What does this error mean? Why would it want to write to this file? The error is there even if I exclude this file from the Project. How do I rectify this?

I renamed the folder from `scripts` to `js` and the problem is still the same. The only way to build successfully was to delete the file. Where then do I place files meant for the client?

Is there documentation available on the Visual Studio project folder structure for a TypeScript/Node project?

Comment: You probably need to create a tsconfig.json. say allowJs to false, and/or use `files`, `include`, `exclude` to tell tsc where to look for files.

Comment: Thanks. I think I need `allowJS` right because this is a Node.js project with lots of Javascript modules? Will look into the other options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the tip by @unional I found my answer, ie, have an explicit `exclude` option in tsconfig.json.

According to [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> the compiler defaults to including all TypeScript (.ts, .d.ts and .tsx) files in the containing directory and subdirectories except those excluded using the "exclude" property. JS files (.js and .jsx) are also included if allowJs is set to true

If `exclude` is not specified, then only node_modules and a couple of others are excluded.  The following worked for me:

```
"exclude":  [ "node_modules", "public"]
```

Note that `exclude` is not a property of `compilerOptions` but is at the same level as `compilerOptions` in tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 3):

Another option that works in VSCode is to use '"outFile":"out.js"' under '"CompilerOptions"' section to have a separate output file.  This way you can still check those files, but not get the writing error.